# PHP PDO multiple database connection options

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm using my localhost to work on my project, but sometimes i need to put the website online to show it for my clients. When i do this i need to change the pdo connection details the webhosting's connection details.

Is there any way in PHP to do it automatically? I mean that i create in various connections, and if PDO cant connect to the first, then tries an another.

```
$option1 = new PDO('mysql:host=host1;dbname=db1', 'user1', 'pw1');
$option2 = new PDO('mysql:host=host2;dbname=db2', 'user2', 'pw2');
$option3 = new PDO('mysql:host=host3;dbname=db3', 'user3', 'pw3');
```

I need a script which tries out each of the options, connects to the right database, and returns a simple $db object.

Comment: Why not just determine what HOST you are on? and then use a switch() to change the details?

Comment: Is my answer works for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
if ($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] == '127.0.0.1' or $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] == '::1')
{
    # LOCAL
    define('dbhost', 'localhost');
    define('dbuser', 'root');
    define('dbpassword', '');
    define('dbname', 'db');
} else {
    # REMOTE
    define('dbhost', 'example.com');
    define('dbuser', 'remoteUser');
    define('dbpassword', 'remotePass');
    define('dbname', 'remoteDb');
}

$conn = new PDO('mysql:host='.dbhost.';dbname='.dbname.', '.dbuser.', '.dbpassword);
```